# How to make a tun interface with ifconfig in OSX?

Tags: mac-osx, load-balancing, tunneling, ifconfig, lvs

If I try to do this I get the following:

```
bash-3.2# ifconfig tun0 10.140.1.40
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Destination address required
```

It sounds like this doesn't happen in Linux (probably this is a BSD thing).  The problem is I need to have a generic tun interface without a specific destination address because I am trying to do LVS-TUN like in this example but I need to use an OSX real server (strange I know).

https://www.rackspace.com/blog/installing-and-configuring-lvs-tun/

What is the way to implement a ipip virtual interface on OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out -- it is WAY easier to use LVS-DR method with OSX.  It turns out disabling ARP for an interface is very simple in OSX and BSD.  One command gets you online:

ifconfig lo0 alias VIP netmask 255.255.255.255 -arp up